In rundeck / terraform, how can I use the option block to capture user input and use it in a command block?
I'm very new to terraform and to rundeck. I am trying to use the option block to capture the input and use it in the command, but I only get errors when using "terraform plan".
What I have tried is the following:
resource "rundeck_job" "my_first_rundeck" {
        name              = var.job_name
    project_name      = var.project_name
    description       = var.job_description
    schedule          = var.job_schedule

    #give the option of choosing from a dropdown list of nicknames
    option {
                name = var.nickname
        label = var.nickname
        required = true
        value_choices = var.nickname_choices
    }
    #give the option of choosing from a dropdown list of scripts,
    #to reduce the error of user input
    option {
                name = var.scripts
        label = var.scripts
        required = true
        value_choices_url = ""
        
    }

    command {
        description = "Testing for ${option.scripts}"

    }
}

I'm trying to figure out how the line description = "Testing for ${option.scripts}" works.
When I use terraform plan it gives me the following error:
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on main.tf line 38, in resource "rundeck_job" "my_first_rundeck":
│   38:                 description = "Testing for ${option.scripts}"
│ 
│ A managed resource "option" "scripts" has not been declared in the root module.

I have another file (variables.tf) where the var.* variables exists
How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Do you have a typo and meant var.scripts? If not, then to what do you expect option.scripts to resolve?

Hi @MatthewSchuchard. No, there is no typo. I meant option.scripts. What I want is to use the option to let the user choose from a dropdown and use that as input in the command script.

You need to "parse" the $ character following this. So, use $${option.opt1} instead of ${option.opt1}
It works in the following way:
command {
  shell_command  = "echo $${option.opt1}"
}

Tested on Rundeck 5.6.0.
